# Can't preview LaTeX fragment in a non-file buffer

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I tried to setup my org-mode according to Bernt Hansen’s wonderful documentation. But later I found I got problem with Org Capture as in Section 6. when I typed C-c c, an error message "Capture abort: (user-error Can't preview LaTeX fragment in a non-file buffer)” occured. After lots of search on the web I still can not solve it. I am wondering is here anyone can help me out? Thanks in advance!

Things I have tried:

1. Test Latex preview in org file [according to this](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html). Both “dvipng” and “imagemagick” setup methods work fine, I can preview Latex formula in .org file.
2. Use the method described here: http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=168c5584f5a41c4c0890f4caa89fc11cff021c4e
   I replace my “org-mode” package with the one in the link which is supposed to solve the problem, however, I still got the same error message.

Versions of some packages I am using:

1. Emacs: GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-21 on builder10-9.porkrind.org
2. AucTeX: 11.88.8
3. org-mode: Org-mode version 8.3.1 (8.3.1-146-gfd8a18-elpa @ /Users/xiaok/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150928/)

Comment: FYI, your link to Bernt Hansen's documentation seems to be broken.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it turns out I can not put more than 2 links. So here is the link to [Bernt's documentation](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html)